# Pushwoosh and Android Phonegap App not communicating

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

### The Problem

Okay so I have a Phonegap (2.3.0) android application with Pushwoosh to manage the push notifications. I followed the instructions, and got an app with only a few wording errors working. The app itself seems to run perfectly fine, however it doesn't seem like Pushwoosh is pushing anything to GCM (Google Cloud Messanger), which it turn isn't pushing anything to the app. Now that is what I think is wrong, however this is my first time using GCM and Pushwoosh.

On the Pushwoosh console page it shows each "push" as completed with no errors, but then on my GCM console it doesn't show any requests, nor do any notification pop up on my phone.

I have the GCM API key (server key) in my XML and my Pushwoosh is the correct XXXXX-XXXXX key. Here is my code to better outline how my code is setup (and maybe someone can see what I'm missing).

---

### The Code

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />


<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<!--library-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

 <!--
Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
    where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
     android:name="com.springmobile.employee.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission
     android:name="com.springmobile.employee.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
     android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>



<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="true">

  <!--
Service for sending location updates
-->
<service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.GeoLocationService"/>
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.springmobile.employee.MESSAGE"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
 </intent-filter>
    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview"/>

    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity"/>

    <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity"/>

    <!--
    BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
    services and handle them to the custom IntentService.

    The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
    so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
    -->
    <receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
    <category android:name="com.springmobile.employee"/>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!--
    Application-specific subclass of PushGCMIntentService that will
    handle received messages.
    -->
    <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService"/>
    <activity android:name="org.apache.cordova.example.cordovaExample" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

Here is my Phonegap plugin config.XML

```
<plugins>
<plugin name="PushNotification" value="com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications" onload="true"/>
</plugins>
```

---

Here is the JS for my Phonegap page to initialize and listen for the Pushwoosh Notification.

```
function initPushwoosh()
{
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.onDeviceReady();

pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "I_HAVE_MY_PROJECT_ID_HERE", appid : "THIS_IS_MY_PUSHWOOSH_ID" },
    function(status) {
        var pushToken = status;
        console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);
    },
    function(status) {
        console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
    }
);

document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
    var title = event.notification.title;
        var userData = event.notification.userdata;

        if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
        console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
    }

    navigator.notification.alert(title);
});
}

function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", initPushwoosh, true);

//rest of the code
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
    var title = event.notification.title;
        var userData = event.notification.userdata;

    console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
    navigator.notification.alert(title);
});
}

function initPushwoosh()
{
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.onDeviceReady();

document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
                            var title = event.notification.title;
                            var userData = event.notification.userdata;

                            if(typeof(userData) != "undefined") {
                                console.warn('user data: ' + JSON.stringify(userData));
                            }

                            navigator.notification.alert(title);

                            pushNotification.stopGeoPushes();
                          });
}

function registerPushwoosh()
{
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
//projectid: "GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID", appid : "PUSHWOOSH_APP_ID"
pushNotification.registerDevice({ projectid: "1039894503284", appid : "EE861-B95A3" },
                                function(token) {
                                    alert(token);
                                    onPushwooshInitialized(token);
                                },
                                function(status) {
                                    alert("failed to register: " +  status);
                                    console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
                                });
}

function unregisterPushwoosh()
{
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.unregisterDevice(function(token) {
                                    alert("unregistered, old token " + token);
                                },
                                function(status) {
                                    alert("failed to unregister: " +  status);
                                    console.warn(JSON.stringify(['failed to unregister ', status]));
                                });
}

//set the settings for Pushwoosh or set tags, this must be called only after successful registration
function onPushwooshInitialized(pushToken)
{
//output the token to the console
console.warn('push token: ' + pushToken);

var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

//set multi notificaiton mode
//pushNotification.setMultiNotificationMode();

//set single notification mode
//pushNotification.setSingleNotificationMode();

//disable sound and vibration
//pushNotification.setSoundType(1);
//pushNotification.setVibrateType(1);

pushNotification.setLightScreenOnNotification(false);

//goal with count
//pushNotification.sendGoalAchieved({goal:'purchase', count:3});

//goal with no count
//pushNotification.sendGoalAchieved({goal:'registration'});

//setting list tags
//pushNotification.setTags({"MyTag":["hello", "world"]});

//settings tags
pushNotification.setTags({deviceName:"hello", deviceId:10},
                                function(status) {
                                    console.warn('setTags success');
                                },
                                function(status) {
                                    console.warn('setTags failed');
                                });

function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    pushNotification.sendLocation({lat:position.coords.latitude, lon:position.coords.longitude},
                             function(status) {
                                  console.warn('sendLocation success');
                             },
                             function(status) {
                                  console.warn('sendLocation failed');
                             });
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function geolocationError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

function getCurrentPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
}

//greedy method to get user position every 3 second. works well for demo.
//  setInterval(getCurrentPosition, 3000);

//this method just gives the position once
//  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);

//this method should track the user position as per Phonegap docs.
//  navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError, { maximumAge: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

//Pushwoosh Android specific method that cares for the battery
pushNotification.startGeoPushes();
}

var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    initPushwoosh();
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    //optional: create local notification alert
    //var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
//pushNotification.clearLocalNotification();
//pushNotification.createLocalNotification({"msg":"message", "seconds":30, "userData":"optional"});

},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
```

---

Here is the PushWoosh.js code

```
(function(cordova) {

function PushNotification() {}

// Call this to register for push notifications and retreive a deviceToken
PushNotification.prototype.registerDevice = function(config, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "registerDevice", config ? [config] : []);
};

// Call this to set tags for the device
PushNotification.prototype.setTags = function(config, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setTags", config ? [config] : []);
};

// Call this to send geo location for the device
PushNotification.prototype.sendLocation = function(config, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "sendLocation", config ? [config] : []);
};

//Android Only----
PushNotification.prototype.unregisterDevice = function(success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "unregisterDevice", []);
};

//config params: {msg:"message", seconds:30, userData:"optional"}
PushNotification.prototype.createLocalNotification = function(config, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "createLocalNotification", config ? [config] : []);
};

PushNotification.prototype.clearLocalNotification = function() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "PushNotification", "clearLocalNotification", []);
};

//advanced background task to track device position and not drain the battery
PushNotification.prototype.startGeoPushes = function(success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "startGeoPushes", []);
};

PushNotification.prototype.stopGeoPushes = function(success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "stopGeoPushes", []);
};

//sets multi notification mode on
PushNotification.prototype.setMultiNotificationMode = function(success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setMultiNotificationMode", []);
};

//sets single notification mode
PushNotification.prototype.setSingleNotificationMode = function(success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setSingleNotificationMode", []);
};

//type: 0 default, 1 no sound, 2 always
PushNotification.prototype.setSoundType = function(type, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setSoundType", [type]);
};  

//type: 0 default, 1 no vibration, 2 always
PushNotification.prototype.setVibrateType = function(type, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setVibrateType", [type]);
};  

PushNotification.prototype.setLightScreenOnNotification = function(on, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setLightScreenOnNotification", [on]);
};

//set to enable led blinking when notification arrives and display is off
PushNotification.prototype.setEnableLED = function(on, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "setEnableLED", [on]);
};

//{goal:'name', count:3} (count is optional)
PushNotification.prototype.sendGoalAchieved = function(config, success, fail) {
    cordova.exec(success, fail, "PushNotification", "sendGoalAchieved", config ? [config] : []);
};

//Android End----

//iOS only----
PushNotification.prototype.onDeviceReady = function() {
    cordova.exec(null, null, "PushNotification", "onDeviceReady", []);
};

// Call this to get a detailed status of remoteNotifications
PushNotification.prototype.getRemoteNotificationStatus = function(callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, callback, "PushNotification", "getRemoteNotificationStatus", []);
};

// Call this to set the application icon badge
PushNotification.prototype.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber = function(badge, callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, callback, "PushNotification", "setApplicationIconBadgeNumber", [{badge: badge}]);
};

// Call this to clear all notifications from the notification center
PushNotification.prototype.cancelAllLocalNotifications = function(callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, callback, "PushNotification", "cancelAllLocalNotifications", []);
};
//iOS End----

// Event spawned when a notification is received while the application is active
PushNotification.prototype.notificationCallback = function(notification) {
    var ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    ev.notification = notification;
    ev.initEvent('push-notification', true, true, arguments);
    document.dispatchEvent(ev);
};

cordova.addConstructor(function() {
    if(!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
    window.plugins.pushNotification = new PushNotification();
});

})(window.cordova || window.Cordova || window.PhoneGap);
```

---

### Screenshots of GCM, Pushwoosh and Eclipse

Sorry this is lengthy but I want to make sure I have everything here. Also not enough rep to post images so links below.

[GCM API server key, Pushwoosh Control Panel, and Eclipse setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgFuX.jpg)

---

**Thanks!**

Comment: i am also facing the same problem. i followed below tutorial http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/

Comment: if u come up wid solution then please tell me.

Comment: Will do, I'm going to work more on it this weekend and see if I can't find a solution. I'll post it here if I happen to find it.

Comment: Hey, thankyou for the reply n if u find the solution plz let me know. I ll be waiting.. Ty.

Comment: You need to comment this line only in PushWoosh.js code cordova.addConstructor(function() { .You should have only if(!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
  window.plugins.pushNotification = new PushNotification();

Answer (score 1):

lets [check](http://devgirl.org/2012/12/04/easy-phonegap-push-notifications-with-pushwoosh/) your configuration and setup is proper for push woosh notification .[Other](http://urbanairship.com/resources/developer-resources) Push notification service is also work in phone-gap you can check it out.You can find phone gap code(zip),proper documentation for configuration and setup and how to use their API using Java script

Comment: Yeah it's setup correctly, well as far as the Pushwoosh documentation shows. Your first link was basically the same thing it just goes into depth as to what each part does. I'd be willing to try another push service, but I can't find one that is as well priced as Pushwoosh (free is amazing).

Answer (score 1):

The Pushwoosh version is very important while configuring it with a phonegap application, so you need to be sure that your Pushwoosh script is compatible with Phonegap 2.3.0.  If the Pushwoosh script is not correct, it will not work with your Phonegap version and I think that they only support the latest Phonegap available right now.

The  GCM API key must be for Android Application, not server

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because my bundle id wasn't correct.
Be sure that your app name and the bundle id are the same in xcode and your iOS app Indentifier in https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers.